# Sidur de nusaj sefardi occidental - Western Sephardic Nusach Siddur

Tags: prayer-book

¿Existe siddur actual de este nusaj solo en hebreo, sin traduccion? O en otro caso el nusaj mas parecido

Is there a current siddur of this nusach only in Hebrew, without translation? Or in another case the most similar nusach?

Comment: @Moises I have used google translate - if it is not doing the question justice, feel free to add your own translation

Answer (score 1):

(Spanish below)

There is a version of the Patah Eliyahou siddur (see link below), which is the most popular Sephardic siddur in France, published in Hebrew only. It includes both Western and Eastern Sephardic nusachs, as it is designed to serve the needs of all sizable Sephardic communities in France.

Where the prayers used by Portuguese and Bordeaux communities (both Western Sepharadim) differ from those used by North African communities, both versions are included and  labelled as such.

The nusach of the Birkhat Hamazon, however, leans heavily towards Western Sephardic. (Though it includes additions for North African nusachs).

Hay una versión del sidur [Patah Eliyahou](https://www.sifreiorhachaim.co.il/product/patah-eliyahou-hebreu-fushia-titre-or/?gclid=CjwKCAjw3ueiBhBmEiwA4BhspAPBLvD4GiFoLq-APRcophGROm5dE-XHnP-dFe52Ivg2R-q1HI_06RoC-KUQAvD_BwE), que el sidur más usado en Francia, que solo contiene texto en hebreo. Incluye y el nusaj oriental y el nusaj occidental, ya que está dirigido a todas las comunidades sefardíes en Francia.

Dónde las comunidades de Portugal y de Burdeos (ambos grupos sefardíes occidentales) emplean una versión distinta a la de las comunidades de África del Norte, el sidur nota ambas versiones.

El Birkhat Hamazon en particular es más occidental que otra cosa.

Comment: It's used in France by Moroccans and Algerians mainly.

Comment: The author was Morrocan

Comment: Don't forget our fine cousins the Tunisians, @kouty! It is indeed mostly used by the groups you stated but it also marks where Portuguese and Bordeaux communities (both Western Sepharadim) use different versions of prayers